# Can you build social networking sites, like facebook, mySpace, or youtube purely with HTML?

Tags: html

I just bought a book of HTML to get a sense of web designing/programming. My final goal is to make social networking sites, although that could be in the far future. Am I going to the right direction? or am I supposed to start with other programming language such as java, PHP or something else. If so, shall I just pass with HTML? or is it worth learning and mandatory for web programming? I'm really confused what HTML can do in a website other than designing.

Comment: HTML is, for sure, one thing to learn. You will need a LOT more.

Comment: HTML, CSS, and JavaScript are the languages that your browser understands. All of the other "web" languages (Java, PHP, ... the list is huge) are primarily meant for generating HTML and other code (JSON, XML, etc.) that is consumed by code running in the browser.

Answer (score 5):

> Can you build social networking sites, like facebook, mySpace, or youtube purely with HTML?

The short answer is *no*

`HTML` is a client side markup language for presenting the page, but you will definitely need server side language e.g. `PHP` to generate *dynamic* `HTML` pages/content

Think about a simple *login* page, `HTML` can only present the page (e.g. username/password fields, buttons etc.) but you need to have a server side logic (e.g. written in PHP, .NET or Java) that handles the actual login process.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is No.

HTML is a markup language that is pretty much exclusively concerned with what the page looks like to the user.  If you include forms and the like in the HTML, then that simply tells the browser to send requests to some server.  And if you embed executable stuff in an HTML resource (for instance Javascript `<script>` elements) then that executable stuff:

- runs on the user's browser,
- cannot store stuff on the user's machine, and
- cannot communicate with anything but the site that launched the page.

A social networking site requires that you can (somehow) communicate with other users on other machines, and can store information somewhere.  Given the above, it should be obvious that a site that simply served up HTML pages cannot possibly do either of the these things.

---

> If so, shall I just pass with HTML? or is it worth learning and mandatory for web programming?

Anything that involves a web based user interface *pretty much* requires you to know HTML.  You just need to learn other stuff too if you are going to implement a website that *does something*.

(I guess it is theoretically possible to implement a web-based user interface where you don't explicitly use HTML, but I doubt this is realistic or practical for a normal application.)

Answer (score 0):

Complex web applications like a social networking site rely on a lot of dynamic content that is generally served up from databases. But HTML is the delivery mechanism, and the foundation of anything you find on the web. You should start by learning HTML, but you're going to need both that AND some kind of programming.

Comment: No, **HTTP** is the delivery mechanism. HTML is the delivered content.

Comment: That's another way of looking at it, sure. I was thinking in terms of  HTML being the descriptor language that tells the browser what to render. The content is the words, images and whatnot that are conveyed to your eyeballs.

Answer (score 0):

Through HTML you can build only static pages but not something complex like social sites. With only HTML you can do something like blogs, which just give pre-made html pages.The moment you start thinking about close interaction with user's through your site; you need to learn lot more.

Social sites require lot more; on client side it requires you to learn HTML, JavaScript, CSS and similarly you need to learn Server side technologies like Java/PHP and then for storing data you need to learn Data bases like MySQL/Oracle DB.